# Where can I initiate the array?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, init

I have a button which performs an action when pressed. I want to add a value to an array. The value is determined after the button is pressed. However, when I initialize the array in the button action, the array resets every time, clearing the array. I want to keep the array values. How can I keep the array values? Should I initialize the array somewhere else? If so, where can I?

Comment: Everything you mentioned seems like a logical flaw on your part, not something to do with its actual behavior. Its impossible for us to give a correct solution without looking at your code :)

Comment: It seems your array is only in a local scope of a method, if you initialize it in the button action.

Answer (score 3):

Before creating a new array, check if there isn't already one.

```
if(!array)
    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// ...

[array addObject:myValueToAdd];
```

Comment: Can I just do !array? Wouldn't you have to define array for it to know whether or not there is one?

Comment: @jsttn Well, `array` should obviously be replaced by the name of your actual array. Or what do you mean?

Comment: Okay. So then are you defining the array in the if statement? If so, how does it know what array is?

Comment: @jsttn Uhm... like Luwe said, it appears like your array is only in the local scope of the action?! If you want to have the array to stay in scope for longer, eg. two button presses, you have to put it somewhere else (you will most likely want to store it in an ivar)

Answer (score 2):

Your statement -

```
"However, when I initialize the array in the button action, 
 the array resets every time, clearing the array"
```

Do not initialize the array in the button action. Initialize it outside as a property of your class or make it global.

In your action for your button, just add the item to your array as `[self.myArray addObject:myObject]`

Comment: Don't make it global, put it in a model class if it doesn't belong in the class with the action method.

Comment: Don't ever use global variables. It's very well settled as an ivar.

Comment: @JoshCaswell You are right. Dont make it global. The idea was to just explain that the initialization has to be one and should be available across all methods.